# How to increment integer in PHP variable with button click?

Tags: php, wordpress, increment

I have WordPress blog posts being loading into a static PHP page on my site. Here is just the relevant code portion. Right now, just 3 blog posts appear but I'd like to be able to load 3 more with each click of the button. And finally, when there are no more posts to load, display the text in id=theend (I am using jquery). Thank you.

```
<?php require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php' ); ?>

      <?php
      global $post;
      $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );

      <div class="row">
      // here is where the 3 posts (title, img, etc.) load
      </div>

      <?php endforeach; ?>

/////////////

<span id="theend" style="display:none">No more posts to display</span>
<button class="btn">Read More</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 100 );
```

And then use jQuery to show/hide 3 at a time. But that is an expensive operation to pull all 100 posts when not everyone is going to look at more than 3 of them.

The other option would be to do an ajax request with each button click to pull the next 3 posts. 
This page has instructions on using AJAX with Wordpress: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/?trm=b&utm_expid=3606929-67.-MP1PYYzS_6mvlSTiltv6Q.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F